# Referencing map values in Go text/template

Tags: go

I have a Golang string:

```golang
 var expressions: = `
{ "text1": "lorem ipsum {{value1}}/12" 
   "text1": "lorem ipsum {{value2}}/24" 
}
`
```

and a map :

```golang
  constants:= map[string]int{
   "value1": 3711,
   "value2":   2138,  
}
```

How to replace values in expressions with corresponding values in the map?

Comment: `{{value1}}` is a function call. Use `{{.value1}}` to get the `value1` field of dot.

Answer (score 1):

To use the value of a `map`, you need to specify the name of the `key` of that field preceded by a period(`.`), such as `.keyName`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    constants := map[string]int{
        "value1": 3711,
        "value2": 2138,
    }

    tmpl := `{ 
    "text1": "lorem ipsum {{ .value1 }}/12" 
    "text2": "lorem ipsum {{ .value2 }}/24" 
}`

    t := template.New("hello")
    tt, err := t.Parse(tmpl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = tt.Execute(os.Stdout, &constants); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ 
    "text1": "lorem ipsum 3711/12" 
    "text2": "lorem ipsum 2138/24" 
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-wl0k-84fcM)

For more complex use-cases, you can take a look at this [code](https://gist.github.com/alex-leonhardt/8ed3f78545706d89d466434fb6870023).